# Why is jackson serializing __type property to null, when annotation clearly states concrete type subtype info?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I have an open api v2 schema that uses allOf and via the openapi-generator-maven-plugin generates the model classes shown below.

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({
  TradeRequest.JSON_PROPERTY_TYPE,
  TradeRequest.JSON_PROPERTY_BUSINESS_DATE
})
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.JavaClientCodegen", date = "2023-02-23T11:48:40.067Z[Europe/London]")
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "__type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ConcreteRequest.class, name = "ConcreteRequest"),
})

public class BaseRequest {
  public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_TYPE = "__type";
  protected String type;

  public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_BUSINESS_DATE = "businessDate";
  private LocalDate businessDate;


  public BaseRequest type(String type) {    
    this.type = type;
    return this;
  }

  @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "")
  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_TYPE)
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public BaseRequest businessDate(LocalDate businessDate) {
    this.businessDate = businessDate;
    return this;
  }

  @javax.annotation.Nullable
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")
  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_BUSINESS_DATE)
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)

  public LocalDate getBusinessDate() {
    return businessDate;
  }

  public void setBusinessDate(LocalDate businessDate) {
    this.businessDate = businessDate;
  }
}


@JsonPropertyOrder({
  EnrichTradeRequest.JSON_PROPERTY_SOAP_TRADE_INPUT
})
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.JavaClientCodegen", date = "2023-02-23T11:48:40.067Z[Europe/London]")
public class ConcreteRequest extends BaseRequest {
  public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_SOAP_TRADE_INPUT = "soapTradeInput";
  private SoapTradeInput soapTradeInput;

  public ConcreteRequest soapTradeInput(SoapTradeInput soapTradeInput) {
    this.soapTradeInput = soapTradeInput;
    return this;
  }

  @javax.annotation.Nullable
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")
  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_SOAP_TRADE_INPUT)
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)
  public SoapTradeInput getSoapTradeInput() {
    return soapTradeInput;
  }

  public void setSoapTradeInput(SoapTradeInput soapTradeInput) {
    this.soapTradeInput = soapTradeInput;
  }
}
```

I have stripped out the equals / toString / hashCode methods.

If I create an instance of ConcreteRequest and the serialize it to json using the object mapper shown below, the __type property is null

```
{
  "soapTradeInput": {
    ...,
    "__type":null
  },
  "__type":null,
  "businessDate":null
}
```

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING);
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.READ_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_INVALID_SUBTYPE, false);
        mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
        mapper.configure(MapperFeature.USE_BASE_TYPE_AS_DEFAULT_IMPL, true);
        mapper.registerModules(new JodaModule());
```

Given that the object graph explicitly uses concrete types and references, I would expect the __type value to be automatically serialized for me and I should not have to explicitly set the property on the object?

I suspect it's a configuration issue, but I am unsure how I go about ensuring the correct concrete type value is used for __type when serializing to json.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `BaseRequest.type` being set anywhere in the constructor, etc of `ConcreteRequest`.

Perhaps you need to do this:

```
    public ConcreteRequest() {
        setType("ConcreteRequest");
    }
```

Comment: The model classes are auto generated from the schema using the openapi-generator-maven-plugin so I cannot modify them manually.

Comment: Then I think you have encountered a defect with that generator (which I have not used), because I cannot see how Jackson can know what type indicator to use on `ConcreteRequest`

Comment: The parent class clearly states

@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ConcreteRequest.class, name = "ConcreteRequest"),
})

So it explicitly know that ConcreteRequest.class should be __type="ConcreteRequest"